# Errors with javafx in default skeleton from intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I just created a simple project based on javafx in intellij idea (i have javafx). When I run intellij idea's skeleton I have so many errors. Help pls

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51146:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Proiecte\SteamINVEST\untitled\out\production\untitled;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\src.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" -p "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x626c7b62) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x626c7b62
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the documentation? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: ```javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java```

Comment: when using fxml you have to add the fxml module in addition to controls

Comment: In other words, use `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`.

Comment: @Slaw where i need to write this command line?

Comment: Check out https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij, it shows you where to put it. However, you appear to already have `--add-modules javafx.controls`, just modify that to include `javafx.fxml`.

Comment: There is a related IDE issue: [IDEA-199616](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199616).